# Populating Multi-Year Calendar Table using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to populate a multi-year calendar table and calculate the value of multiple fields based on the date. I'm running this script on Postgres, it is taking forever to run even if I pass start_date as 2023-02-16 and end_date as 2023-02-17. Please help with what is wrong here.

[image]

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: Noted. It was not letting me post with code as the description was very less compared to the code

Comment: try generate_series(), that is so much easier to use, you don't need plpgsql at all, no loop and much faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example using generate_series():

```
INSERT INTO t1(....)
SELECT 
    (g.d)::date AS date,
    EXTRACT(year FROM g.d) AS year,
    EXTRACT(month FROM g.d) AS month,
    EXTRACT(day FROM g.d) AS day,
    EXTRACT(quarter FROM g.d) AS quarter,
    EXTRACT(week FROM g.d) AS week,
    EXTRACT(isodow FROM g.d) AS isodow,
    EXTRACT(doy FROM g.d) AS doy,
    EXTRACT(isoyear FROM g.d) AS isoyear
   FROM generate_series('1970-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone, '2049-12-31 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone, '1 day'::interval) g(d)
 ORDER BY g.d;
```

Just change the table name t1 and the columns you need. It take 0.1 second on my laptop to generate and insert 29220 dates.